# Running only certain junit tests in a project by file name

Tags: eclipse, junit

So i have an eclipse project, with a bunch of junit test files. I want to run all of them, except ones that have a certain suffix (or inversely, only those that have one of a set of suffixes).

Eg, i can do this in maven; i can run all tests in a project that are in files that end in "Test", and all other files are ignored.

I want to do something similar in eclipse w/o having to configure things; just based on names. Right now i would go to "run configurations.." and then select "run all tests in a selected project..", but it'll run everything it finds in there; i want to omit files based on their suffix.

Is there a way to do this in eclipse?

Comment: See if the my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314834/how-to-exclude-a-test-from-a-test-application-using-eclipse-android-junit-launch) helps. It is related to Android, but similar for configuring JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options:

- Use [cpsuite](https://github.com/takari/takari-cpsuite)
- [Exclude them from your build path](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9385962/2448440)
- Create a test suite like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/457299/1137529) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1645369/1137529)