# Running parallel junit tests on multiple remote machines

Tags: java, testing, junit

I'm working on a pretty large project with junit tests running several hours.  Is there a way to distribute unit tests to different machines and run these tests in parallel?

Comment: You might be able to split up your tests into different "packages" and execute these in parallel - Like so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489838/running-only-certain-junit-tests-in-a-project-by-file-name

Comment: That's a good thought, they are already broken into many packages.  What I'm looking for though is the least painful way to run them across multiple machines simultaneously and combine a "report".  I'm not sure that is described in the other answer (or I missed it or something).

Answer (score 1):

What about a build runner like Jenkins and a maven or gradle like build setup.

Possibly something like http://test-load-balancer.github.com/ as a distributed testrunner is not available from gradle at the moment http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/distributed_testing

Comment: Your first ilnk is broken.